# Searching for FEM library

Tags: library, c++, math

I need a [FEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) library in c++ language that supports finite elements with C1 continuity. At first I wanted to use [Fenics](http://fenicsproject.org/), because the documentation mentioned some non-conforming elements, but then I realized that they are not supported. Now I am out of clue. Does anybody have any suggestions?